# Variables in modules not displaying

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of my script. I have created a module  that has a method for getting and filtering computers in AD, which looks like this:

```
function Get-FilteredADComputers {
    $global:site = Read-Host '
Which site?

site1
site2

                '
    Clear-Host
    $global:computerType = Read-Host '
Client
Server
'

    $global:OU = "OU=$global:computerType,OU=Devices,OU=MyOU,OU=$global:site,OU=My OU,DC=mydomain,DC=.com"
    $global:computerSelection = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $global:OU | select -ExpandProperty "Name" | sort
    $global:computerSelection
    $global:computers = @()

    $global:filter = Read-Host '
Input computer filter. For all computers use a single *.'
    $global:computers += $global:computerSelection | where {$_ -like "$global:filter"}
    $global:computers

    return $global:computers
}
```

This module is imported to my main script like this:

```
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\Modules\SetInfo\SetInfo.psm1" -DisableNameChecking -Force
```

Now, when I call this method it should output during execution which computers it finds, and this works if I call the method with no variable assigned to it, like this: `Get-FilteredADComputers`, when the method runs it outputs all the computers it finds as it should.

However, if I call the method and assign it to a variable this:

`$filteredList = Get-FilteredADComputers`, during execution, it does not output anything.

Comment: Why is everything global?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That's a good question. I was confused why there was no output so after reading a bit about it, people were mentioning scopes. So I attempted to make everything global to see if that was the issue.

Comment: That `$filteredList = Get-FilteredADComputers` doesn't _output_ anything is to be expected, given that you're _capturing the output_ in variable `$filteredList`. Or are you saying that `$filteredList` receives no value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grossly simplify what you're doing.  It is unnecessary to select ALL computers with every query:

```
function Get-FilteredADComputers
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.String[]])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('site1', 'site2')]
        [System.String]
        $Site,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('Client', 'Server')]
        [System.String]
        $ComputerType,

        [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.String]
        $Filter
    )

    $OU = "OU=$ComputerType,OU=Devices,OU=MyOU,OU=$Site,OU=My OU,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
    (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '$Filter'" -SearchBase $OU).Name | Sort-Object
}
```

That being said, I'm not seeing what you're experiencing.  You are actually returning `$computers` twice in your example script -

```
$computers
return $computers
```